# How do I change values of several cells in a data frame based on cell data type using for loop or any faster method./function?

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, data-science

I have data set of over 100,000 rows and 10 columns. these 10 columns should have numeric values but 1% contents in these 10 columns are alpha and alphanumeric.

how do I use FOR loop or any faster method/function to change the values of all alpha and alphanumeric cells to mean of each column or to any numeric values?

e.g.  column a b c & d

a   b   c   d

1   2   5   f5

5   e5  9   6

tg  56  8   r5

q2  4   75   g

above dataset is just an example.

I am looking for any solution you may have.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `pd.to_numeric`, more details [here](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.to_numeric.html). This will make the column numeric.
You can add the key-word argument `errors = 'coerce'`, which will replace unconvertible values like the ones containing alphanumeric characters with `NaN`. You can then replace these NaNs with the mean value of the column later, using `DataFrame.fillna`.

`pd.to_numeric` only works on Series, so you would have to do it on each column, but you can also apply it to the entire DataFrame like this:

```py
df = df.apply(pd.to_numeric, errors = "coerce")
```

Full example:

```py
df = df.apply(pd.to_numeric, errors = "coerce")
df = df.fillna(df.mean())
```